# With SQL Server, I am trying to insert variable values into a Bulk Insert command with no success

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @dash VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @dlabel VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @fname VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Script VARCHAR(2048)

SELECT
    @filename = SUBSTRING(filenames, CHARINDEX('PSM', filenames) ,CHARINDEX('.csv', filenames) - CHARINDEX('PSM', filenames)) , 
    @month = CASE SUBSTRING(filenames, 47, 2)
                 WHEN '01' THEN 'jan' 
                 WHEN '02' THEN 'feb'
                 WHEN '03' THEN 'mar'
                 WHEN '04' THEN 'apr'
                 WHEN '05' THEN 'may'
                 WHEN '06' THEN 'jun'
                 WHEN '07' THEN 'jul'
                 WHEN '08' THEN 'aug'
                 WHEN '09' THEN 'sep'
                 WHEN '10' THEN 'oct'
                 WHEN '11' THEN 'nov'
                 WHEN '12' THEN 'dec'
                 END, 
    @day = SUBSTRING(filenames, 49, 2), 
    @year = SUBSTRING(filenames, 43, 4),
    @dlabel = CONCAT(CASE substring (filenames, 47, 2)
                         WHEN '01' THEN 'jan' 
                         WHEN '02' THEN 'feb'
                         WHEN '03' THEN 'mar'
                         WHEN '04' THEN 'apr'
                         WHEN '05' THEN 'may'
                         WHEN '06' THEN 'jun'
                         WHEN '07' THEN 'jul'
                         WHEN '08' THEN 'aug'
                         WHEN '09' THEN 'sep'
                         WHEN '10' THEN 'oct'
                         WHEN '11' THEN 'nov'
                         WHEN '12' THEN 'dec'
                     END, '_', SUBSTRING(filenames, 49, 2), '_', SUBSTRING(filenames, 43, 4))
FROM  
    dbo.files
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING(filenames, 40, 3) = 'PSM'
    AND filenames LIKE '%.csv%';


SET @fname = 'oars_results_final_' 
SET @filename = CONCAT(@fname, @month, @dash, @day, @dash, @year)
SET @dash = '_'
SET @path = '/Users/Public/' + @filename + '.csv'

SET @script= 'BULK INSERT ' +  @filename + ' FROM ' + @path + 
             ' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'', BATCHSIZE = 250, MAXERRORS = 1)';

EXEC @Script;
```

Upon execution, I get the following error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 145
> Could not find stored procedure 'BULK INSERT oars_results_final_oct292021 FROM /Users/Public/oars_results_final_oct292021.csv WITH (FIRSTROW = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR='\n',BATCHSIZE=250,MAXERRORS=1)'

I am not using the `@variable` correctly I believe.

Comment: `EXEC (@Script)`. `EXEC @Script` means execute the **procedure** with the name of the variable, *not* execute the script contained in the variable. See [Using EXECUTE with a stored procedure variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-execute-with-a-stored-procedure-variable) Voting to close as typographical. Though if you used `sys.sp_executesql`, like you should be, you wouldn't have had this error.

Comment: I'd love to know why you have a separate table for every file. Side point: you have an injection risk here, you should be using `QUOTENAME(@filename)` and `QUOTENAME(@path, '''')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) a code in a string, you need to put the string argument in parenthesis.

```
...
exec(@Script);
...
```

(Discalimer: I haven't checked if the code in the string is correct or makes any sense.)

Comment: Better yet, don't do `EXEC (@SQL)` at all. Use `sys.sp_executesql`.